# Redirect::back() is not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

```
if(count($data) == 1){
            return view('welcome');
        }
        else {
            // echo "dslkfjads";
            Redirect::back()->with('message','Username or password not Match!'); 
        }
```

Above Redirect::back() function is not working while login. If I'm printing anything it is showing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to return a response object, so your code should looks like this:

```
if (count($data) == 1) {
    return view('welcome');
} else {
    return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Username or password not Match!');
}
```